# How to highlight keyboard led using current locale

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, locale, capslock

How does one make the keyboard led show his current locale? It might be useful for users using two locales (languages).

Desired behavior:

- capslock led on keyboad is `OFF` for your first locale (english, for example)
- capslock led is `ON` for your second locale (russian, for example)
- capslock led changes when you're switching windows (from a window with "ru" to a window with "en")

Answer (score 1):

A solution for a debian-based distribution:

- run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. You can set up the capslock switching here (altrough it would not activate keyboard led by default). (Skip for non-debian distr.)
- open `/etc/default/keyboard`  (find an alternative for non-debian distr.)
- find `XKBLAYOUT`. You should see something like "us,ru" inside. If not, edit this line.
- find `XKBOPTIONS`. Set this inside: `grp:caps_toggle,grp:switch,grp_led:caps`. The `caps_toggle` and `switch` mean switching layout by capslock (skip if you only want keyboard led, not switching). The `grp_led:caps` means to use the led for layout indication.
- reboot the system or apply changes immediately if you know how. For debian-based distros it's `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.